# How can I handle having clicked() and doubleClicked() at the same time in qtableview?

Tags: qt

I am trying to use both doubleClicked() and clicked() signals with qtableview, but when I have them both, only the clicked() signal works, but the other one doesn't, how can I resolve this?

Comment: Please share your code, especially the way you connected the signals.

Comment: This is **not** true. There is something wrong in your code. I have wrote a minimal example [here](http://pastebin.com/CU6Mzf8A), and it works as expected (single clicks trigger `clicked()` signal, double clicks trigger `clicked()` followed by `doubleClicked()`).

Comment: I don't know, maybe because I am using qt 4?

Comment: here is a link how to get the Qt version: http://linux.m2osw.com/find-qt-version-command-line-compile-time-run-time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have extended QTableView and redefined mouseDoubleClickEvent like so:

```
void TableView::mouseDoubleClickEvent ( QMouseEvent *event )
{
    emit(doubleClick(this->indexAt(QPoint(event->pos().x(), event->pos().y()))));
    event->accept();
}
```

and it works now.

Comment: what version of Qt are you using? does the `doubleClicked` get emitted if you try [my example](http://pastebin.com/CU6Mzf8A)?

Comment: @Mike, actually, I don't even know, I use a virtual machine with an unknown version of some old linux for work, and I couldn't even create a new project there, you have to configure every project by hand somehow in this OS, so, I'm sorry, but I can't answer your question.